# Как ЗАМЕНИТЬ текст в txt, который при этом извлекается из txt, используя .replace()

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть txt файлы и inputbox

file1.txt , file2.txt, inputbox

Конкретно:

Код, который заменяет слово в file1.txt(которое берёт из file2.txt), при этом в file1.txt все написано в одну строку. Заменяет на другое слово, которое берёт из inputbox и вписывает новое слово в file2.txt для последующей замены

Либо подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить определенные данные в txt, если всё написано в одну строку

Comment: Если бы вы увидели такой вопрос, смогли бы разобраться в том, что человеку требуется?

Comment: Прикрепил схему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, что я правильно трактовал Ваш алгоритм и схему.
**Код будет выполнять следующие шаги:**

- Открываем файл `file2.txt` и читаем из него слово, которое нужно
  заменить в файле `file1.txt`;
- Открываем файл `file1.txt` и читаем из него всю строку. Заменяем в ней
  найденное слово на новое слово, которое введет пользователь;
- Записываем измененную строку в файл `file1.txt`;
- Записываем новое слово в файл `file2.txt`.

**Решение:**

```python
# Открываем файл file2.txt и читаем из него слово для замены
with open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    old_word = f.read().strip()

# Ввод слова
new_word = input("Введите новое слово для замены: ")

# Открываем файл file1.txt и заменяем старое слово на новое
with open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = f.read()
    new_line = line.replace(old_word, new_word)

# Записываем новую строку в файл file1.txt
with open('file1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(new_line)

# Записываем новое слово в файл file2.txt для последующей замены
with open('file2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(new_word)
```

**Наполнение `file1.txt`:**

`Семь раз в неделю old_word ждет меня в степи. old_word я любил Вас`.

**Наполнение `file2.txt`:**

`old_word`.

В данном конкретном примере `inputbox` происходит через терминал, но Вы можете использовать `new_word = inputbox`.

Хочу обратить Ваше внимание, что в этом примере файлы имею кодировку `utf-8`, у Вас оно может быть другим, что потребует изменения файлов.

Так же это не выглядит, как самое оптимальное решение. Возможно в дальнейшем Вам придется развить код, таким образом, чтобы выполнялся поиск старого слова в тексте, которое ищет пользователь.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Очень рад, что Вам подошло это решение. Успехов в Ваших проектах :)